# How does one use a certain version of Horizon when requesting?

Tags: horizon, paths

I would like to use the 0.23 version of Horizon in this particular query below. How does one do that?

```
var server = new StellarSdk.Server("https://horizon.stellar.org");

  var sourceAsset = new StellarSdk.Asset(
    "USD",
    "GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX"
  );

  var sourceAmount = "15.4008989";

  var destination = [new StellarSdk.Asset("XLM", "")];

  server
    .strictSendPaths(sourceAsset, sourceAmount, destination)
    .call()
    .then(function(pathResult) {
      console.log(pathResult.records);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any given time, the latest Horizon release can be found here: https://github.com/stellar/go/releases

Horizon 0.23 is released [here](https://github.com/stellar/go/releases/tag/horizon-v0.23.0). Anyone can download and run it, although it requires a small amount of technical know-how. You can follow the [Quickstart guide](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/quickstart.md) to get something up quickly to play with. It should only take a few minutes.

Alternatively, you can simply wait. Typically the latest Horizon release is deployed to the official SDF servers at horizon.stellar.org two days after the release. You can confirm the Horizon version (`horizon_version`) in the JSON data at the root URL (https://horizon.stellar.org).

Comment: 0.23 is now up.